# Concept of Dynamic CSS using PHP

Tags: php

In many of the website and frameworks, you can find that the referenced CSS is something like this:

```
"myCSS.css?key=akc223nk"
```

This simply means that myCSS.css is being passed with some parameter if I am not wrong. And in some case, the entire myCSS file would not even exist.

Using PHP how can create such dynamic files.

Comment: Just get apache or httpd or whatever you're using to parse `.css` as `.php`. Then use `.css` as if it were a php file.

Comment: "This simply means that myCSS.css is being passed with some parameter". Not wrong, but incomplete. The most common reason for this is to force the server to serve the file, regardless of whether or not the client might have it cached. The server does not actually generate CSS in this case, it just serves a static file.

Comment: Plus, you can just reference to *.php in your `<link>` HTML, if you're able to send this PHP's output with a "text/css" Content-type header. But like @Amadan said, you don't really need it.

Comment: How about sending  a temporary file to the client machine?

Comment: What temporary file? Why?

Comment: @SergeyVidusov: There are couple of reasons for this. I am developing a library which can be used to shared servers. Shared Servers will not give access to change httpd.conf.
Apart from this, this library is expected to work without session. So, what key shall I pass there without saving the key to database.
Temporary file means, create a CSS file on runtime in the Server file system which can be deleted after sometime (say 5mins)

Answer (score 0):

you can create an htaccess rule

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule myCSS.css phphandler.php [L,QSA]
```

[QSA] is important as it forwards the Query String Arguments over to your PHP code.

Now you can go to somepage.com/myCSS.css?key=akc223nk and your server will actually serve phphandler.php?key=akc223nk in the background :)

To create a temporary file:

```
if(!file_exists('myCSS.css') || (time() - filemtime('myCSS.css')/ 60) > 5) {
   //5 = 5 minutes, you can change it to whatever
file_put_contents('myCSS.css',$data);
}
```

This will create/overwrite your css file after 5 minutes with w/e content. if you need to push it to the client, then you can add this below:

```
header('Content-Type: text/css');
readfile('myCSS.css');
```

Comment: How about an approach where I create a temporary file to the client

Comment: you can create the temporary file in PHP, i updated my answer...
Not sure if that's what you need, if not let me know

Comment: any luck @VeerShrivastav ?